# If $\cos48^\circ\cos42^\circ = p$ and $\sin48^\circ\sin42^\circ = q$, find $\cos6^\circ$ in terms of $p$ and $q$

Tags: trigonometry

> If $\cos48^\circ\cos42^\circ = p$ and $\sin48^\circ\sin42^\circ = q$, find $\cos6^\circ$ in terms of $p$ and $q$

How to do this? I've tried for long and I'm not coming right.

Will it be $\cos (48^\circ+42^\circ)$ or $\cos (48^\circ-42^\circ)$

Whats the next step?

Comment: Use the angle addition formula for cosine.

Comment: ... $48$ what ?

Comment: @G. Sassatelli Degrees...

Comment: Do you know $\cos (A-B) $? Take$ A=48, B=42$.

Comment: Yes but now how would you convert that in to terms of p and q?

Comment: Why do not take the Hint and work the problem out instead of waiting for someone to give you full solution and you learn nothing?

Comment: I tried but i can't get the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice the cosine angle difference identity: $$cos(A-B)=cosAcosB+sinAsinB$$

Replacing all instances of $A$ and $B$ with $48$ and $42$ respectively will result, $$cos(48-42)=cos48cos42+sin48sin42$$

From this, you can now express $cos6$ using $p$ and $q$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$\cos(6)=\cos(48-42)$$

Use trigonometric identities.

Comment: How will that be expressed in terms of p and q?

Comment: @MyV:  Use the cosine difference angle identity.

Comment: @MyV I'm sorry if my hint wasn't helpful, I didn't have the time for a full explanation.  I hope all of the other wonderful answers have answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

By the formulas for sum and difference of sinus and cosinus and a little calculation one has 
$$\cos 15x+\cos x=2\cos 8x\cos7x$$ and $$\cos 15x-\cos x=-2\sin 8x\sin 7x$$

Hence $$2\cos x=2(p+q)$$ and $$\color{red}{\cos 6^{\circ}=p+q}$$